# How long is the temporary shielding in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was recently promoted to Diamond V in League of Legends. I have heard that you are shielded from being demoted the first 10 games. However I was wondering how long the shield lasts, not in terms of games but time-wise. What I mean is whether there is a temporary time-frame where the shield expires regardless of how many games are played (ex: I play only 5 games in a 28 day period yet the shielding expires due to time) or whether the shield acts indefinitely until you play the 10 games (ex: I play once every 3 weeks and the shielding applies until I hit the 10th game even though it has been months after the promotion). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "shielding" in League of Legends.
You only drop from a V division if your hidden elo is lower than the elo you need for the V division in the prior league.

*For clarification:* You can lose as many games till you reach an elo of an Gold V player, then you will drop to Gold I.

**But:** You can also drop a division when not playing for a month!

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing with this on a smurf account a while back with the 3-5 game shield from before. Picked it up a month afterwards(Silver Elo).

If we  assume the diamond V shield performs in the same way.
The shielding/protection from demotion appears to outlast a month(1 1/2 month when i returned to it) as time progresses, as I just hit S1, and lost a few games off the bat.

**However**

> DEMOTIONS AND DECAY
>   WHAT IS DECAY?
>   If you are in Platinum or Diamond, after 28 days of inactivity in a particular ranked queue, a couple things will happen. First, you’ll be hidden from the standings in your league. You will also lose LP depending on your current tier. Every seven days thereafter, you’ll lose LP until you play a match in that queue.
>
> In the Master and Challenger tier, players will decay after becoming inactive for 10 days; this is to ensure only the top active players are being showcased.
>
> The number of LP lost following each period of decay is shown below:
>
> Master & Challenger: 250
>   Diamond: 50
>   Platinum: 35
>   If you fall at or below zero LP as a result of decay, you’ll be placed into the next lowest division. If you’re already in division V of your tier, you’ll fall into the next tier down (for example, Platinum V to Gold I.). Tl;dr: don’t take a break from ranked for too long. :)
>
> Decay does not occur for players in Bronze, Silver, and Gold.

So because I did the test in silver, I didn't receive any decay. If you are inactive for too long as a Diamond V, you will be demoted by decay. The shielding does not protect against decay.